# Automatically do this when saving

Tags: vba, excel

how can I let this code run everytime I save the ecxel sheet?

```
Sub export_pdf()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"E:\09-Prozessvisualisierung.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True,IgnorePrintAreas:=False,OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

I already tried this. But didn't work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Sub export_pdf()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"E:\09-Prozessvisualisierung.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,OpenAfterPublish:=True


End Sub
```

[Picture of the VBA-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hvwx.jpg)

Comment: Just copy your code into the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, inside the `Workbook` module

Comment: like this?                                                                                                        Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Sub export_pdf()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"E:\09-Prozessvisualisierung.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 
End Sub

Comment: without the `Sub export_pdf()` and `End Sub`. Or you can keep this entire Sub, and just add `Call export_pdf` inside the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)` event  - your choice

Answer (score -1):

Write the whole code inside the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

(Note: I recommend not to use `ActiveSheet`, if you can help it).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "E:\09-Prozessvisualisierung.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code but it doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: you copied my entire code (only option 1), saved your workbook and nothing happened?

Comment: That's right. I tried the second one two.bud didn't work either.

Comment: @gpp - It's worth noting that if you want to run the export_pdf procedure at any other time in the code as well, you can simply place the procedure name `export_pdf` inside the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event and leave it as `export_pdf` as a stand alone procedure.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I had it as a second option, but now im trying to also answer another question the PO has (in his answer below), so I focused on this option